# How to check third party AMI's running in my AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

Nowadays I'm using *AWS* a lot for my projects. I'm learning about *AWS AMI*.

1. How can I know whether the third party AMI's running in my AWS
   account?
2. Is it possible for someone to run their AMI's in my
   account?
3. Can I set up a notification system using AWS CloudWatch so that I
   can get the notifications every time someone runs his AMI in my
   account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is a copy of a boot disk.

When you start an Amazon EC2 instance, you must select an AMI. The contents of the AMI will be copied to the boot disk of the instance. An AMI contains the operating system (Windows or Linux), together with other software that was installed when the AMI was created.

**How can I know whether the third party AMI's running in my AWS account?**

You can't directly *run* an AMI. Rather, you can launch an Amazon EC2 instance that uses an AMI. Only somebody with permission to use your AWS account can launch an Amazon EC2 instance.

If you look at the details of an Amazon EC2 instance, it will show the name and ID of the AMI that was used when the instance was launched.

**Is it possible for someone to run their AMI's in my account?**

Only somebody with permission to use your AWS account can launch an Amazon EC2 instance.

**Can I set up a notification system using AWS CloudWatch so that I can get the notifications every time someone runs his AMI in my account?**

You can use Amazon CloudWatch Events to be notified when an Amazon EC2 instance is launched in your account, but only somebody with permission to use your account can launch an instance.

**Bottom line:** Other people can't do things in your account unless you create an IAM User and give them a set of access credentials.

Comment: Thanks a lot again :-). It's very helpful.